# How to insert white spaces between certain character positions, irrespective of what the character is?

Tags: python, string

The column is called df['Col1']. Where the number of characters within the column is equal to 10, I want to add 2 blank white spaces between the 5th and 6th character of each string, otherwise only add one space between the 5th and 6th character.

For example RPYHVBN56I becomes RPYHV__BN56I, and any strings with more or less characters only input one space, such as RPYHVBN56I00000 becomes 
RPYHV_BN56I00000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].map(lambda s: s[:5] + ('  ' if len(s) == 10 else ' ') + s[5:])
```

Comment: It returns the error, 'str' object has no attribute 'str'?

Comment: I already edited it, but why does that error appear? What's happening? Can I also ask [:5] I'm assuming means fifth character?

Comment: @Sam `s` as a single value is already string. `.str` is required when you want to call a string function for an entire `series`. `[:5]` means characters from start until position 5, e.g 0-4 positions - the first 5 chars.